# ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 - bit not working on bootable usb

Tags: usb, 64-bit, software-installation

hello i went to download Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit and went to make my bootable usb and followed the steps and everything correctly and the usb showed install Ubuntu but when i went to setup my laptop and disable safe boot and change the usb to first in the boot order it keeps telling me there is no bootable image/file or something along those lines like was there something i missed or didn't do or is there a problem that people have been experiencing when downloading Ubuntu 32-bit/64-bit like it being a damaged download or whatever any help would be greatly appreciated as i am new to Ubuntu and the forums and would love to learn from you more experienced folks and become more knowledgeable with the Ubuntu Linux OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Linux Live USB Creator to make my linux bootable USB. It is pretty intuitive and works fine. You can get it for Windows at [Linux Live USB Creator.](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/linux-live-usb-creator/)

Comment: thanks for the reply :) and yea that's what i used and still had problems with it not being able to boot

Comment: I have a Lenovo laptop and in BIOS there is an option called USB Boot which can be either enabled or disabled. Maybe you should check if your laptop has something similar.

Comment: that fixed it i knew i was messing something else thank you again though for the help :)

Comment: Glad to help :)